# Can not create flutter project

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

I am new to whole, flutter and dart! While creating flutter app via command line in windows(running flutter create app_name), I am getting following error:
**Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...**

Comment: does it require internet connection? because when i created another app while doing nothing else differently, it was a success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need internet connectivity to retrieve the necessary packages and potentially plugins from [Pub](https://pub.dartlang.org).

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the clarification.